# Read null characters from file into string

Tags: c, string, file

I have created a function where I can read the first x amount of bytes from a file. The file is a binary file, and contains NULL characters. I am trying to read the file into a char* however it gives an incorrect length because I am appending NULL characters to the string. Is there a workaround to storing data from a file in a string

```
    // readlen is the amount I want to read from the start of a file

    FILE* fptr = fopen(path, "rb");

    char* contents = (char*)malloc(readlen + 1);
    int read = 0;
    int ch;

    while ((ch = fgetc(fptr)) != EOF && read != readlen) {
        contents[read++] = (char)ch;
    }

    contents[readlen] = '\0';
    fclose(fptr);
    return contents;
```

Comment: You have to keep track of the used length of the array instead of treating it like a string.  The caller needs a way to get the final value of `read` in that. (Oh, and consider `fread()` instead of that loop )

Comment: Every string is terminated by the first null byte at or after the start of the string.  That's the definition of a [string](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.1p1).  You want to read byte arrays, and you will have to keep track of the length of the byte arrays since the null byte is no longer a valid sentinel indicating the end of the byte array (whereas it is a valid sentinel indicating the end of a string).

Comment: _The file is a binary file..._ then treat it as arbitrary binary data, not as string data. As you've found out, these are not the same and a mistake to treat them as such. Throw any string functions and idioms you may be using (`contents[readlen] = '\0';`) out the window, and instead maintain the length of data yourself (as already suggested), use [`memcmp`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcmp.3.html) if you want to compare its contents, etc. Also recommend changing that to `unsigned char* contents`, just for more clarity you're dealing with bytes and not a pointer to a string.

Answer (score 2):

First, a terminology misconception in the title "Read null characters from file into string". In C, string can not contain NUL characters, because those mark end of the string. A char buffer can contain them, but it's not a string. And when it is not a string with an end marker, you need to keep track of its length.

---

Then, to solve your problem, you could return a struct with the information

```
struct buffer {
    char *contents;
    size_t size;
};
```

---

With that, the code you show becomes something like this:

```
// readlen is the amount I want to read from the start of a file

FILE* fptr = fopen(path, "rb");

struct buffer buffer;
buffer.contents = (char*)malloc(readlen + 1);
buffer.size = 0;
int ch;

while ((ch = fgetc(fptr)) != EOF && buffer.size != readlen) {
    buffer.contents[buffer.size++] = (char)ch;
}

buffer.contents[buffer.size] = '\0';
fclose(fptr);
return buffer;
```

---

Further improvement of your function would be to use `fread` to do the read with one function call. You might discover, that your own function becomes unnecessary and you could just directly call `fread`, even.

Also, putting extra 0 at the end of the char buffer might not be useful, since it is not a string, but it doesn't really hurt and will be convenient if you ever read a text file and want to print it or something. Still, unless you have some specific need for it, I'd consider removing that extra byte.

Comment: It would probably be better to use `fread` so we can fill the entire buffer in a single read if possible.

Comment: @Locke It certainly would be better. This is just the minimal answer to the question.